# Full screen not showing buttons when using custom toolbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-table

I've come across a weird issue which I'm unsure if it's me or a bug.

Using only basic HTML the problem is occurring when using "data-toolbar="#toolbar" and have "data-show-fullscreen="true"" however when entering full screen the toolbar is hidden and no where to be seen making it impossible to exit full screen without a page refresh.

Comment: Can you setup a JSFiddle demonstrating the issue?

Comment: JSFiddle is at https://jsfiddle.net/8yhm6cdz/ when you click the fullscreen icon there's no way to exit

Answer (score 0):

It seems that happens because you have custom `div` for the toolbar, but it seems to work if:

- you remove `data-buttons-toolbar=".buttons-toolbar"` and `<div class="buttons-toolbar"></div>`

or

- play around with css, but setting `position` and `z-index: 10001` does make the toolbar appear